# What to do with a question that appears sensible but turns out to have a trivial cause?

Tags: discussion, self-answer, trivial

I saw [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44927643) (now deleted; [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BRpfm.png)) that at first seemed sensible, but it appears the cause (and the fix) was trivial.

- Should we ask the OP to delete their question?
- Should we ask the OP to post an answer to their question so it doesn't appear in Unanswered?
- Should we leave it as-is and let the world decay?

Comment: I would close it with "A problem that can no longer be reproduced....".

Comment: @BDLI forgot the 3rd option. Closing. That makes sense.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> Should we ask the OP to delete its question?

You can ask, if you're polite about it, although in this case the post will end up meeting the criteria for automatic deletion in a week, so that's not really necessary, and is likely enough to just upset them if they don't take it right.

> Should we ask the OP to make a valid answer to this question, so it doesn't appear in Unanswered ?

They can't, because the question is closed, and we wouldn't want them to, for exactly the reason the question has since been closed as.

> Should we let it like it is and let the world decay :) ?

You could vote to delete it, if you have the privilege, and don't want to wait 7 days.  You could downvote it to help improve the likelihood that the question will still meet the automatic deletion criteria in a week (by making it harder for the post to get back up to a positive score by that time).  There's not really anything else that you'd *need* to do.

Had the question not yet been closed, you could vote/flag for closure of course.

Comment: I flagged it for closing before you answered. I asked the first Q because I did not know about the automatic deletion process. Thanks

Comment: @MatM, Automatic deletion is done by the Roomba script. You can see the criteria for automatic deletion of questions [on this page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/roomba). If you desire, I wrote a user script, [Roomba Forecaster](https://stackapps.com/questions/7239/roomba-forecaster-when-will-the-question-be-roomaed-if-it-wont-why), which will place a note on each question page telling you if/when the question will be Roomba'ed or why it won't happen (if the question doesn't qualify to be Roomba'ed).